# How to auto scroll a ScrollPane so that a node will be aligned at the top of the pane

Tags: java, javafx

In my program, I have a ScrollPane which its content is a VBox with a lot of child nodes. Some of the nodes are links which you can click and it should jump to the link's destination (imagine clicking the links in the Contents in a Wikipedia article, it will jump to the corresponding section). I know that in order to vertically scroll the ScrollPane by code, I would use `.setVvalue()`.

My thinking is that I will get the y-coordinate of the link's destination node and divide it by the content's total height, and use that value as the `Vvalue`. The problem is that how would I accurately get the y-coordinate of a node if it's nested in multiple containers (e.g. in 2 VBoxes) using `.getBoundsInParent()`? Also, am I even approaching this the correct way?

An example of what I mean:

[Before clicking the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ee8Ti.png)

[After clicking the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3lXK.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `localToParent` multiple times to transform coordinates from the coordinate system of the `ScollPane`'s `content` node:

```
public static Point2D transform(Node coordinatesNode, Node ancestor, double x, double y) {
    Point2D coordinates = new Point2D(x, y);
    while (coordinatesNode != ancestor) {
        coordinates = coordinatesNode.localToParent(coordinates);
        coordinatesNode = coordinatesNode.getParent();
    }
    return coordinates;
}
```

You could e.g. use

```
Point2D pt = transform(someNode, scrollPane.getContent(), 0, 0);
```

To get the coordinates of the top-left of `someNode` in the content of `scrllPane`.

> My thinking is that I will get the y-coordinate of the link's destination node and divide it by the content's total height, and use that value as the Vvalue

This is not 100% correct. You need to include the fact that for `vvalue = 1` the bottom of the content is shown at the bottom of the viewport not at the top. Therefore the equation for the y coordinate of the content part shown at the top of the viewport is

```
y = vvalue * (contentHeight - viewportHeight)
```

so

```
vvalue = y / (contentHeight - viewportHeight)
```

You need to treat cases where `contentHeight <= viewportHeight` or `y > contentHeight - viewportHeight` seperatly of course.

The height of the viewport can be retrieved via the viewport bounds

```
double viewportHeight = scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getHeight();
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate explanation! After using your method and revising my equation for the vvalue, my program now works perfectly!